# How to get live data from a DDE link in R?

Tags: r, quantitative-finance, dde

I have an application that gives `=MTX|DATA!'OTKAR.GUN.F%'` when asked for DDE link.
It works perfectly fine with Excel.

There seems to be only tcltk2 but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: can you please provide some more information as to what you trying to do? Perhaps some more R code and the error messages you are receiving

Comment: I am trying to get live price of a stock from an application through DDE link and use it in R. There is no code besides this info.

Comment: Do you have any R Code? other than that one line above. Providing some more code and the error will help me try reproduce what you have done and solve the issue at hand.